# Which MIME type should be used for a raw image?

Tags: mime-types

[Raw images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) are produced by cameras, scanners, etc. and typically give you more post-processing flexibility than JPEG images.

**If I’m serving this kind of file from my web server, which media type (a.k.a. MIME type) should I use?** I’m specifically interested in the CR2 files produced by recent Canon cameras, but answers could also address Adobe’s Digital Negative (DNG) format or raw files from other manufacturers’ cameras. (I didn’t see anything relevant in [this list from the IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [this XML file](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-raw-thumbnailer/blob/0ea8d2387cb595109cd6aeff5bc2b4fe51f4b2be/data/raw-thumbnailer.xml) from the (defunct?) GNOME RAW Thumbnailer project, the MIME type for raw images in general is image/x-dcraw. Listed by their file extensions, here are the other file types mentioned in that file:

- ARW: image/x-sony-arw
- CR2: image/x-canon-cr2
- CRW: image/x-canon-crw
- DCR: image/x-kodak-dcr
- DNG: image/x-adobe-dng
- ERF: image/x-epson-erf
- K25: image/x-kodak-k25
- KDC: image/x-kodak-kdc
- MRW: image/x-minolta-mrw
- NEF: image/x-nikon-nef
- ORF: image/x-olympus-orf
- PEF: image/x-pentax-pef
- RAF: image/x-fuji-raf
- RAW: image/x-panasonic-raw
- SR2: image/x-sony-sr2
- SRF: image/x-sony-srf
- X3F: image/x-sigma-x3f

Comment: The XML file linked in the answer does not seem to exist anymore. This one should be a valid copy: https://github.com/angryziber/gnome-raw-thumbnailer/blob/master/data/raw-thumbnailer.xml

Answer (score 4):

It might be too late for the author of the question, but might be helpful for others struggling with the same problem.

For `.CR2` it is `image/x-canon-cr2`.

For `.DNG` it is `image/x-adobe-dng`

(Edit: the original post said `.CR2` was `image/dcraw2`, but modern tooling like ExifTool render `image/x-canon-cr2`. FWIW, neither are registered mimetypes: see [the IANA website](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image) for the canonical list).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any sources you can cite for these values?

Comment: Yes. Here are some sources which helped me: [Gnome thumbnailer](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-raw-thumbnailer/blob/master/data/raw-thumbnailer.xml) and [question](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/398472) on Adobe forums. 
Both of types from my answer work well when I try to upload such files to Google Drive.

Answer (score 2):

Using the convention of [Gnome raw thumbnailer](https://github.com/angryziber/gnome-raw-thumbnailer/blob/master/data/raw-thumbnailer.xml) might be an option but MIME is assigned by IANA based on reference standards and/or requests of the vendors, so is certainly a non-uffical way even though these are the MIME the vendors are using. The list of official IANA MIME can be found [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). All the other list are actually unofficialial. Also, the [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_graphics_file_formats) is often not updated.

If the MIME is not present in the list you could extract it using tools such exiftool and looking for MIME Type.
I would also consider to use `application/octet-stream` which is an official MIME type and is used for unknown types of binary data as explained in [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt), at least the application will know that it is a binary file.

If you don't like this solution or a MIME used by the vendors and need to disambiguate from multiple RAW image files, I would follow the convention used for other proprietary image types in the standard: `image/vnd.<manufacturer>.<filename extension>` for instance for NEF by Nikon corporation and .mrv for Minolta:

```
image/vnd.nikon.nef
image/vnd.minolta.mrw
```

But of course this is a pure speculation and will be not recognized by other application.