# Does codeigniter allow raw images upload?

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-s3, upload, dropzone.js

Codeigniter is not allowing uploading raw image files (CR2, NEF, DNG etc..) with following configuration.

I'm using **dropzone.js** to upload image/video files.  On dragging the files to dropzone window, files get uploaded to temp folder and on submitting, they're moved to desired storage location.

I'm able to upload files with mime_types `image/jpeg|image/png|image/gif|video/*`.  However, raw image files with extension `.CR2!.DNG` etc are not getting uploaded.  It always throws the error **`You did not select a file to upload`**.

On analysing, I found that the default 'upload' library allows only `jpeg|png|gif` and other jpeg supported image formats.

```
 $config['upload_path'] = './upload_files/temp/';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg|cr2|dng|srf|mp4|mov|mpg|mpeg|wmv|mkv';
 $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
 $this->load->library('upload'); 
 $this->upload->initialize($config);

 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
  $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
  header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
  return $msg;
 } else {
      ....
 }
```

Is updating *upload* library to allow required file types the **only** option OR are there other options exist?

Secondly, if the files are to be uploaded to different storage server viz., AWS S3 or others, is it always wise to upload to local temp folder and then push it to remote server?

TIA

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473056/which-mime-type-should-be-used-for-a-raw-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your mime type configuration file @ config/mimes.php and add

```
'dng'   =>  array('image/x-adobe-dng'),
'cr2'   =>  array('image/x-dcraw', 'image/x-canon-cr2'),
```

you find a list of mime types for raw images [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473056/which-mime-type-should-be-used-for-a-raw-image)

**update resuming comments:**

RAW files are rather large files, so make sure the image-size is met in your php.ini settings: change `post_max_size` accordingly.

It works on php 7.2.20

Comment: Hey @Vickel, Thanks for this.  Added the mime types, restarted the apache server and tried uploading a `.CR2` file.  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: what's the file size?

Comment: upload file size is 21MB; in php.ini the values are set `max_execution_time = 360`; `upload_max_filesize = 40M`

Comment: OK, I've just double-checked, it doesn't work on php 5.5.0 (on my localhost), here I need to $config['allowed_types']        ='*' to make it work) but it works on my shared production server with php 7.2.20 (I have not changed the php.ini, it's ok up to 8 MB files)

Comment: Well, the default value `post_max_size` parameter was 8M and after revising it, upload is successful.  Thanks for your support.